# Adding Product SKU to Authorize.net Merchant Email Receipt

Tags: authorize.net

We would like to add product SKU info to the "Merchant email Receipt" we receive from authorize.net.  Is this possible?  Right now we are just getting the following product info along with addresses/shipping info:

========= ORDER INFORMATION =========

Invoice : XXXXXXX

Description :

Amount : 365.65 (USD)

Payment Method : MasterCard

Type : Authorized and held for review

I'm new to magento and i've dug around in the templates, but i am getting nowhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Authorize.net doesn't allow for the customization of such.  Only adjustments to the header and footer of the emails.

- https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/how-can-i-edit-the-email-receipt/m-p/22813/highlight/true#M12316

You should be able to have Magento instead send the order notifications & disable emails from auth.net to both customer and admins and can adjust these accordingly:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/customizing-transactional-emails

Comment: Thanks - is CIM something that would work? http://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/

Comment: My understanding is Magento uses the AIM method of implementation, there are 3rd party modules that support CIM version. Heres a comparison: https://developer.authorize.net/api/compare/

Comment: Thanks again.  If we disabled notifications from auth.net and went for magento - which notifications/emails would need to be configured?

Comment: never mind - it doesn't appear that the Order Update emails are configured by default.  This is what I added.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Authorize.net Direct Post

Take a look at `setDataFromOrder` in `Mage_Authorizenet_Model_Directpost`  (/app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Model/Directpost/Request.php)

Then take a look at Authorize.net DPM API for [Itemized Order Information](http://developer.authorize.net/guides/DPM/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Additional_Fields.08.3.html)

You will need to create a custom module to override Directpost then add

```
foreach($order->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
    //$xLineItem = format according to api
}
$this->setXLineItem($xLineItem)
```

Also take a look at https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php

***After reviewing our authorize.net "Merchant Email Receipt" the item detail still will not show.*** See [Merchant Email Receipt without product details](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Merchant-Email-Receipt-without-product-details/td-p/6438)

> The Item ID will not show up in the Merchant email receipts. It is only available through the Transaction Details API, Transaction Details page in your Authorize.Net account and Customer email receipts.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible, then.

Comment: No, not on the "Merchant email receipt" but you may want to double check if you want or need this info in other places in authorize.net